# Twitter website causes rapid disk activity

Tags: hard-drive, performance, chromium, twitter

When I have Twitter open, there is rapid disk activity. Especially if I am scrolling down the feed or have multiple Twitter tabs open. How can I debug this or isolate the website from acessing the hard drive? This is in Chromium on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the cache and profile in tmpfs using [the instructions on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chromium#Tmpfs) resolved this issue. I.e. using the `--disk-cache-dir="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/chromium-cache"` parameter with chromium and using [profile-sync-daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Profile-sync-daemon)